# R - lat/long from a start point and distance

Tags: r, gis, spatial

I have lat and lon coordinates. Because I needed to rotate them I transformed the WGS84 lat/lon coordinates into distances from a given point and rotated around that point using a rotation matrix. But for plotting reasons I now need to transform the newly rotated distance values (x and y) back into WGS84 lat/lon coordinates. But I can't find a way to do it.

I transformed the initial lat/lon values to distances from a chosen point like this:

```
g_mat_x <- cbind(lon, rep(sp_lat,length(lon)))
dist_x <- distGeo(c(sp_lon,sp_lat),g_mat_x)
g_mat_y <- cbind(rep(sp_lon,length(lat)),lat)
dist_y <- distGeo(c(sp_lon,sp_lat),g_mat_y)*(-1)
```

Where `sp_lon` and `sp_lat` are the coordinates of the freely chosen point. `lon` and `lat` are vectors from the measurement with the cordinates I needed the distances to.

This works great, but I can't get my head around on how to transform the distances back into the corresponding lat/lon values using the same point (`sp_lon`/`sp_lat`).

Are there functions around capable of doing that?

Sample data:

```
sp_lon <- 6.5
sp_lat <- 54.1
```

The lat and lon data can be found here:

`https://pastebin.com/8ZMGkG2P for lat values`

```
lon <- c(7.03922544225856, 7.03921652830416, 7.03920761347249, 7.03919870033677, 
7.03918980775434, 7.039180893677, 7.03917198029713, 7.03916306606371, 
7.03915415091448, 7.03914523638381, 7.03913632276797)
```

`https://pastebin.com/bz4zRDb4 for lon values`

```
lat <- c(53.8599307418054, 53.8599299782294, 53.8599292147252, 53.8599284513955, 
53.8599276909077, 53.8599269276675, 53.8599261646716, 53.8599254016427, 
53.8599246387294, 53.8599238760691, 53.8599231135803)
```

results for distances from distGeo:

`https://pastebin.com/b1rK2i0H for dist_x`

```
dist_x <- c(35275.2396149456, 35274.6564815661, 35274.0732907975, 35273.4902109736, 
35272.9084757064, 35272.3253342833, 35271.7422384877, 35271.1590868543, 
35270.5758753102, 35269.9927042311, 35269.4095929985)

dist_x_rot <- c(27157.4079196703, 27156.82265961, 27156.2373461817, 27155.6521449452, 
27155.0683243199, 27154.4830661607, 27153.897859114, 27153.3125971812, 
27152.7272807104, 27152.1420106127, 27151.556803262)
```

`https://pastebin.com/tL7qhXwk for dist_y`

```
dist_y <- c(-26720.819753436, -26720.9047412656, -26720.9897211144, -26721.0746815378, 
-26721.1593256438, -26721.2442761088, -26721.3291993745, -26721.4141263143, 
-26721.4990403831, -26721.5839262974, -26721.6687931261)

dist_y_rot <- c(-34940.2337323618, -34940.1648982768, -34940.0960416297, -34940.0271949336, 
-34939.9583906952, -34939.8895184371, -34939.8206317157, -34939.7517340913, 
-34939.6828085284, -34939.6138662435, -34939.5449210127)
```

I hope it is okay this way. I'd rather give you a small part of the real data instead of making up data.

**EDIT:** Okay, I got it using destPoint and simple trigonometry to get the dist vector and the angle.

Comment: `geosphere::destPoint`: destination given bearing (direction) and distance (from a known point(s)).

Comment: I already had a look at `destPoint`, but I don't have a bearing and my distance is split into `x` and `y` values. As far as I understand `destPoint` it expects a single numeric vector not a matrix.

Comment: I understand, and while you do give the code you used to convert, it would be helpful to have sample data to understand what all is going on.

Comment: I added small snippets from my data. Hope it is okay over pastebin, but I rather use real data instead of artificial data for a minimal example

Comment: Thank you for providing data. While links can be acceptable, when they go stale the question becomes unreproducible and sometimes less clear. Additionally, I don't think we need 1000 points to get the point across, I'd think 5-10 would be more than sufficient. Can you use something like `dput(head(...))` and post the output in addition to the links?

Comment: True! Added small examples (10 values) from the real data. Also added the distances after rotating.